# Would like to get suggestion on compare date entered and today's Date in dialoge flow CX

Tags: googlebot, dialogflow-cx

I am little new to google dialog flow cx. I have scenario where I need to compare a date which is user entered with today's date and find if it is past date or present/future. I have a call flow based on the condition.

I am trying to take today's date and parse then compare day, month and year. Maybe there could be another solutions.